# Php-script ran outside apache gets "Permission denied" when opening cookies

Tags: php, session

Allright. This is an interresting one.

I am writing a socket server where i want to authenticate connecting users by passing their session id from the browser, and then loading some data about the user using that session.

Cool, right? Sadly, it was not going to be that simple. When i try to set the current session in php using `session_id();`, i get these errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getUsername() on null in /home/#website#/public_html/api/socketserver/authenticateduser.php on line 35

PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/lib/php5/sessions/sess_2rkcsmjc6p7nj8ourihsdofeu3, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5/sessions) in Unknown on line 0
```

**Can i see some code?** Yes!

```
static function AuthenticateUser($session, $sessionid) {
    echo "Authenticating session id " . $sessionid . "\n";
    echo "session data: " . exec("cat /var/lib/php5/sessions/sess_" . $sessionid) . "\n";
    session_id($sessionid);
    //session_start();
    $user = Session::getCurrentUser();
    echo "Authented user " . $user->getUsername();
}
```

Please note that i am still prototyping this code, so nothing is complete, and this may not be the final design.

So, the first error happens because `Session::getCurrentUser()` returns null. This is understandable, as we aren't logged in by default, and the target session is never loaded(shown by errors below). Why the errors are below are beyond me.

The two other errors are because of some file permissions.

**Have you tried X?**

- **Have you tried running as root?** Yes. I even ran `exec("cat /var/lib/php5/sessions/sess_" . $sessionid)` to prove i could read from the session file. Still no dice. This is why this case is so wierd.
- **What are the permissions?** /var/lib/php5/sessions has rwxr-xr-t, and is owned by www-data. The session files inside have -rw------- permissions, and are owned by www-data.
- **What OS are you on? What versions?** Ubuntu 15.04 with php 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2
- **Does apache and php share the same session save path? You DO know php.ini are different for cli and apahe?** Yes.

This issue has bothered me for the past days, but because php had issues even when i ran the script as root, i am a bit perplexed.

Comment: check `open_basedir` php ini option

Comment: use the same user to read sessions and to run apache